# How to add to a Binary Search Tree without using a Node class

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree, addition

For class I need to create my own binary search tree implementation including a search,add, remove and toString method but I cannot try those methods without add first. I am not allowed to write or use a node class. Each node of my tree is supposed to be an instance of the BinarySearchTree class. I cannot figure out how to traverse the tree without the typical nodes. Here's my first portion of code:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> implements BinarySearchTreeInterface<E> {
    E value;
    BinarySearchTree<E> parent;
    BinarySearchTree<E> left;
    BinarySearchTree<E> right;
    static String draw;

    public BinarySearchTree() {
        value = null;
        parent = null;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(E item) {
        if (isRoot() && value == null) {
            value = item;

        } else if (value.compareTo(item) > 0) {
            if (right != null) {
                add(right.value);
            } else {
                BinarySearchTree<E> newNode = new BinarySearchTree<E>();
                newNode.value = item;
                newNode.right = newNode;    
            }
        }else if (value.compareTo(item) < 0) {
            if (left != null) {
                add(left.value);
            }
          } else {
            BinarySearchTree<E> newNode = new BinarySearchTree<E>();
            newNode.value = item;
            newNode.left = newNode;
        }
    }
```

This seems to only add the root value of 5. I believe it has something to do with not connecting the new "node" to the parent or maybe my constructor. I am struggling to traverse the tree and connect the "nodes" without using a node class.

Comment: try to use right.add(item); and left.add(item) instead of add(left.value);

Comment: I just noticed you have a method called isRoot() that you didn't include... How does it work?

Comment: @LowKeyEnergy it checks if(parent == null); the root doesn't have a parent so it returns true if the node is the root. The code works now after fixing the recursion statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at it this way... Every node of a binary tree is itself a binary tree.

If you consider the two as equivalent, then your `BinarySearchTree` class is actually a `Node` class... it's just not named "Node" .

Any time you want to use an object of class `Node`, just declare it as a `BinarySearchTree` Instead.

Instead of having:

```
Node left;
Node right;
```

You will have:

```
BinarySearchTree left;
BinarySearchTree right;
```

And by the way, what you are missing is this:

```
this.left = newNode;
```

or

```
this.right = newNode;
```

It means that the `BinarySearchTree` is setting the `left` or the `right` variable of *itself*. That's what `this` means.

As it turns out, the `this` is not even necessary except in some cases where the context is ambiguous. In your case, you can just say:

`left = newNode;`

or

`right = newNode;`

Comment: thank you! I had realized that I wasn't setting the left and right to my new node but it seems like where ever I add that statement into my add method it causes a StackOverflowError.

Comment: Stack overflow indicates that endless recursion is occurring. Any time you make a recursive call, you need to be sure that the call you make is solving a smaller "problem" than the recursive call you are in.